# Rust decode aes

Tags: rust, aes

I am trying to decode a string with rust. I can decode it in js with CryptoJS, but it isn't working in rust with openssl.
`error Err(ErrorStack([Error { code: 101077092, library: "digital envelope routines", function: "EVP_DecryptFinal_ex", reason: "bad decrypt", file: "crypto/evp/evp_enc.c", l ine: 612 }]))`

```js
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, "24408752.37717366").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
```

```rs
use openssl::symm::decrypt;
use openssl::symm::Cipher;

static SALT: &'static [u8] = b"24408752";
static KEY: &'static [u8] = b"37717366";

let cipher = Cipher::aes_256_cbc();
let key = openssl::pkcs5::bytes_to_key(cipher, openssl::hash::MessageDigest::md5(), KEY, Some(SALT), 1).unwrap();
let new_data = decrypt(cipher, &key.key, key.iv.as_deref(), message);
```

Comment: Since you use a password in the CryptoJS code, a key derivation function (`EVP_BytesToKey()`) is applied. Thus, this function must also be used in the Rust code (which is currently not the case). If you would apply a key in the CryptoJS code instead of a password, this wouldn't be necessary. Also, both codes seem to use different modes (CBC vs ECB).

Comment: If I look at the error message, and simply compare [the example in the documentation](https://docs.rs/openssl/latest/openssl/symm/index.html) with the code here, then the example has a key length of 16, and the code here has a key length of 17. The former corresponds to an AES key length of 128 bits, in line with one of the normal key sizes for AES.

Comment: CryptoJS works differently: the second argument is not the key, but [a passphrase that is transformed into a (256 bit) key](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input).

Comment: This is really a case of: read the error message, read through the documentation, and start counting (the lenght of the strings/byte-literal).

Comment: For the key derivation function see [`openssl::pkcs5::bytes_to_key`](https://docs.rs/openssl/latest/openssl/pkcs5/fn.bytes_to_key.html) with MD5 as digest and 1 as count. The CryptoJS code requires the Base64 encoding of the ciphertext in OpenSSL format: `<Salted__>|<8 bytes salt><actual ciphertext>`, from which the salt can be extracted. Together with the password, a 32-byte key and a 16-byte IV can be derived from this (for the default AES-256 in CBC mode). This allows the actual ciphertext to be decrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rs
let message_d = base64::decode(message).unwrap();
let cipher = Cipher::aes_256_cbc();
let key = openssl::pkcs5::bytes_to_key(cipher, openssl::hash::MessageDigest::md5(), KEY, Some(&message_d[8..16]), 1).unwrap();
let new_data = decrypt(cipher, &key.key, key.iv.as_deref(), & message_d[16..]).unwrap();
println!("{}", new_data.iter().map(|e| *e as char).collect::<String>());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).